# Removing a point from a set of i.i.d. points.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

Let $n$ datapoints are sampled iid from a distribution $\mathcal{D}$. If we remove a single point (point having maximum leverage score) after looking at all the points, can we say the remaining $n-1$ points are iid?

If we sample $n$ points from a Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and remove all the points less than zero, then the remaining points can not be said to be sampled from a Gaussian, but are they independent? What is the mathematical characterization of the remaining set of points?

Also, if possible, please mention any reference to read about such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading about [censoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)) and [truncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_(statistics)).